# UnsatisfiedLinkError: mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to call C++ functions from Scala but facing some issues while building connections.

While trying to connect C++ Functions from Scala code, I followed these steps.

**This is my C++ example function (example.cpp):**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    void printSomething() {
        std::cout << "Hello from C++!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Compiled it into a shared library using the following command:**

```bash
g++ -shared -o libexample.so example.cpp
```

**Created a Java class with native methods:**

```java
public class NativeLibrary {
    static {
        System.load("/Users/xyz/xyz/app/test2/libexample.so: ");
    }

    public static native void printSomething();
}
```

**Generated the Java header file (NativeLibrary.h):**

```
javac NativeLibrary.java
javah NativeLibrary
```

**Scala code to call the C++ function:**

```scala
object Main extends App {
    System.load("")
    NativeLibrary.printSomething()
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/xyz/xyz/app/test2/libexample.so: dlopen(/Users/xyz/xyz/app/test2/libexample.so, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/roohein/app/test2/libexample.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/xyz/xyz/app/test2/libexample.so' (no such file), '/Users/xyz/app/test2/libexample.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
    at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:2)
    at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:1)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:75)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:576)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:904)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:75)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:73)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:1)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

and if I replace `System.load()` with `System.loadlibrary()`,
it is unable to find the library even in same directory path.

I tried it in many other ways as well, like bridging using JNI and Java headers file, but I am still getting the same kind of error and I am unable to resolve this issue.

This is my Java configuration:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.282.08.1 (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.282.08.1 (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')` are you compiling and running on different machines?

Comment: You seem to be on a Mac. The library extension should therefore be `libexample.dylib`. And you somehow compiled the library for the wrong architecture.

Comment: Also, embrace modernity and adopt a modern JDK.

Comment: Also that native code is not following JNI expectations. Learn about how to use JNI.

Comment: @fukanchik I am compiling and running it on same machines

Comment: @Botje Yes, I figured that out and tried with .dylib extension  still getting Linkage error

Comment: @aled can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You need to  tell us where you got g++ from, for starters. If it is actually a link to clang++ you can set the desired architecture from there. I bet you have a g++ from brew somewhere that is hard coded to amd64.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your JVM expects a library of architecture x86_64, while you have a Mac with Apple Silicon with architecture arm64.

You should investigate where you got this JVM from and install one that is natively arm64.

Alternatively you must use a cross-compiler (such as `clang++` with a correct `-target`) to produce a x86_64 library that your existing JVM can load, but that means cross-compiling *all* dependencies.